# How to run json-server in windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, json-server

I have installed json-server using npm in Windows. Now when I try to run the json-server command from the Windows command prompt, I get this error:  `json-server is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Does anybody have any info on what is required to be changed here?

Comment: A search for the error message (*not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*) shows many existing questions, all of which share a common solution. Did you try reading any of them?

Comment: @KenWhite  Yes and none of them apply to me , since I cannot set any env variables in my system which is blocked by administrator . It's an organization system and I don't have access and so, I have posted the question here to see if there is any alternative solution .

Comment: Any and all  of them apply to you.  You either add the directory of `json-server` to your PATH, specify the absolute path when calling it, or change into that directory before calling it. Those three solutions  are outlined  in many of the posts that the search would have located. Reading one or two of them and deciding *none of them apply to me* is not appropriate. And nothing in your question says anything about not being able to set env. variables or not having admin privileges - we can't  know that if you don't  tell us, because we can't read your mind.

Answer (score 6):

Try this (with npm versions after 5.2.0):
`npx json-server db.json`

Comment: **Precisely** the same problem as the O.P.  This did the trick for me...

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this in PowerShell `npm install -g json-server`
2. Run `json-server .\db.json`

After this your server should be running on `http://localhost:3000/posts`